# Unable to determine HOST_OS from uname -sm: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 x86_64

Tags: android, shell, cygwin, android-source

In order to import the project of android source code（`revision="refs/tags/android-7.1.0_r1"`） to android studio, I follow the step:

windows 7 64bit, cygwin, input this command:

```
$ mmma development/tools/idegen/
```

encounter the problem:

> `build/core/envsetup.mk:72: *** Unable to determine HOST_OS from uname -sm: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 x86_64`

[image]

the src directory is the android source code，like this：
[image]

I don't know what happen, and I can't find any message about this problem, so I hope to look for help

Comment: linking image is very bad. Please post the text instead. Look also on build/core/envsetup.mk before row 72 to see the expectation of the code. Likely they have not considered or mishandled the cygwin case

Comment: Kindly read [ask] before asking your next question. Good luck, and tell us if you solve it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I had solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem. Just add the environment variables HOST_OS "cygwin\bin".

First step:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA4v0.png)

Second step:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amZJg.png)